# SELECT after INSERT doesn't select recently added rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is quite a basic and somewhat strange question, I guess. Suppose I have a stored procedure that contains an `INSERT` (or `MERGE`) statement, followed by a `SELECT` statement.

Can I always assume that the `INSERT` statement has finished writing/committing data when I run `SELECT`? Is it to be expected that the `SELECT` statement (sometimes) doesn't select all recently inserted rows? If so, what options do I have to make the `SELECT` statement wait for the `INSERT` statement to have finished (in a stored procedure) or include possibly uncommitted data?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that when a statement finishes then all the data is correctly put into the database.  This is related to the ACID properties of databases and one of the reasons why relational databases are a popular technology.

Comment: Just to add-on, if you want to make sure that data is successfully inserted, just use a variable and set it to 1 after insert and then check if the variable value is 1 then use the select statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So what should I do if it doesn't?

Comment: Newly inserted/updated data will always be visible to the current session once the statement successfully completes. In the case of a transaction that is not autocommitted (e.g. explicit transaction) data will also be visible to other sessions when the transaction is committed.

Comment: Have a look at the "output" clause on the "insert" statement but yes, you will always be able to see them. The "select" will not run until the "insert" completes.

Comment: @BlackLight Up to now I used output clauses only for MERGE. I'll add them also for DELETE and INSERT to see where exactly the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the same session it will see it , whether committed or not, unless it has been rolled back.

Once committed other sessions can see it.

Answer (score 0):

If 'select' is from different session and you want read uncommited data

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Comment: From what I've read this has a lot of side-effects I don't want. I need reproducible results.